# Is there any difference between "render new" and "render new.html.erb"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `create` action in my `users` controller:

```
def create
  @user= User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    #success action filled
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

and the test to check if the template on wrong invalid user inform:

```
test "user input error" do
  get signup_path
  assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
    post users_path,user:{name:"raj",email:"sad",password:"sad",password_confirmation:"sad"}
  end
  assert_template 'new'
end
```

is passing. but when I change the `render new` to `render new.html.erb`, it fails.

```
expecting <"users/new.html.erb"> but rendering with <["shared/_error_messages", "users/new", "layouts/_shim", "layouts/_header.html.erb", "layouts/_footer.html.erb", "layouts/application"]>
```

These are other layouts in the page. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Normally you'd see this as `render(action: 'new')`. Specifying the full filename is problematic as it forces a particular response type where you might have several formats supported.

Comment: I usually use `render :new`, but when I just did a test `render :new` and `render 'new.html.erb'` both work?  I would probably just stick to `render :new` though.